# Projecting an ellipse defined on a sphere onto the XY plane

Tags: vectors, analytic-geometry, projection, ellipsoids

I want to find the equation for and the area of the ellipse defined by $\Theta_H$ and $\Psi_H$ when it gets projected onto the XY plane.

The following diagram shows these ellipses.

[image: Solid Angle Ellipse]

Let us suppose we know the radius $r$. I know that I can approximate the major and minor axes of the ellipse via:

$$ a = 2 r \text{tan}\left(\frac{\Theta_H}{2}\right) $$
$$ b = 2 r \text{tan}\left(\frac{\Psi_H}{2}\right) $$

If I could find the vector equation of the ellipse, then I could just set the z component to zero to project it onto the XY Plane.

---

**Questions:**

1. What is the vector equation for the ellipse? I.e. the 3D xyz equation.
2. Is there another way to do this projection rather than approximating the curve with a ellipse in a plane, finding the equation for that plane, and then setting the z component to zero?

Comment: 1) Could you indicate the document where you have found this illustration ? 2) You must be aware that this curve isn't a true "ellipse" because it's not a plane curve ; otherwise, it would mean that the intersection of the plane - where this curve would be situated - with a sphere would be an ellipse and at the same time a circle.

Comment: @JeanMarie  1.) Van Tree's Optimum Array Processing 2.) Yes I know. It is just an approximation. If you can define the actual curve then please help me out here. This area really isn't my strongsuit.

Comment: The figure looks clearly flawed. The upper end of the ellipse on the sphere is a little to the left of a line of longitude, but it is projected down (via a dotted line) to a radial that is distinctly to the right of that line of longitude. If we believe the projection on the plane it seems the axis of the ellipse lies on a radial, but if you look at the ellipse on the sphere it seems its axis should not project onto a radial.

Comment: @DavidK I think my problem still stands though. I can figure out the Theta_H and Psi_H via outside data, I just need to find the corresponding ellipse in the XY plane.

Comment: For the area it may not matter (much), but for the ellipse equation the orientation of the axis matters. The figure is very unclear how the orientation of the ellipse is determined.

Comment: Also, if you start with a symmetric figure on the sphere in the position where the "ellipse" is shown, it will not project onto an exact ellipse on the plane below. Not to mention there is no standard definition for an "ellipse" on a sphere, so we don't know really what curve it should be. With all these flaws in the definition, I think any additional error you would introduce by "approximating the curve with a ellipse in a plane" would be relatively minor. Honestly, I think method 2 looks like the best way to go.

Comment: @DavidK I would think so. If you could define the plane solution, I would be most grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let : $a:=\frac12 \Theta_H$ and $b:=\frac12 \Psi_H$.

Let $(\psi_0,\theta_0)$ be the spherical coordinates of center of the curve.

A first parameterization is

$$\begin{cases}\psi&=&\psi_0+a \cos(t)&(i)\\\theta&=&\theta_0+b \sin(t)&(ii)\end{cases}\tag{1}$$

i.e., a "true ellipse" wrt coordinates $(\psi,\theta)$ parameterized by a 'non-physical" parameter $t$.

In a second step, we plug these expressions in the classical cartesian/spherical formulas:

$$\begin{cases}x&=&\cos \psi \cos \theta&(i)\\
y&=&\sin \psi \cos \theta&(ii)\\
z&=&\sin \theta&(iii)
\end{cases}\tag{2}$$

One gets the projection onto the $xy$ plane, indeed, by plainly suppressing parameter $z$ in (2).

---

Edit (2023-04-16): Let us go a step further.

Let us show how to get a *polar* equation for this projected curve.

First of all, as the projection can be written :

$$\binom{x}{y}=\cos\theta\binom{\cos \psi}{\sin \psi},$$

it means that the polar equation of this curve is

$$r=\cos(\theta) \ \ \iff \ \ r=\cos(\theta(\psi))\tag{3}.$$

The second form in (3) stresses the fact that we desire to express $\theta$ as a function of $\psi$ in order to get finaly the polar equation under the forme $r=F(\psi)$ for a certain function $F$.

Using first (1)(ii), then (1)(i), we have :

$$r=\cos(\theta_0+b \sin(t))=\cos(\theta_0+b \sin(\cos^{-1}(\tfrac{\psi-\psi_0}{a})))$$

Otherwise said :

$$r=\cos\left(\theta_0+b \sqrt{1-(\tfrac{\psi-\psi_0}{a})^2}\right)$$

which is the function $r=F(\psi)$ we were looking for.

Calculating (in a numerical way here) the area enclosed by a polar curve is easy : it is

$$\frac12 \int_{\psi=0}^{2 \pi} r^2 d\psi$$

Comment: And I suppose that $t \in [0, 2\pi)$ correct? Well it wouldn't really matter but that is the whole of the domain without wrapping really.

Comment: Yes $[0,2\pi)$. What do you mean by "without wrapping" ? What are your needs, in fact ?

Comment: I want to find the equation of the ellipse in the XY plane 
so I can find its major and minor axes and also its area. This solution gets me mostly there though as I can devise a program to calculate those things for me (numerically) from here.

Comment: This could get a little weird when the "ellipse" is near the pole. I don't think it can produce the circle shown around the pole in the illustration.

Comment: My method gives parametric equations : the  major and minor axes of the pseudo-ellipse you will obtain are given by the projections of extreme points corresponding to $t=0, t=\frac{\pi}{2},t=\pi,t=\frac{3\pi}{2}$.

Comment: @JeanMarie Indeed :-)

Comment: Yes, this is classical : representation $(\psi,\theta)$ is known to have a singular point in the pole. You cannot deal with curves turning around the pole. For doing so, I advise you to work with **stereographic projection**.

Comment: @JeanMarie I assume that you are using theta as latitude and not colatitude?

Comment: Yes, as latitude.

Comment: @JeanMarie  If it were co-latitude, then we would have x= sin(theta) cos(psi) and y = sin(theta) sin(psi) z = cos(theta) correct?

Comment: That's right...

Comment: @JeanMarie Okay just making sure -- answer accepted. Thanks for helping :-)

Comment: Happy it has helped. As said upwards, just have a look at stereographical projection : it has very interesting properties.

Comment: @JeanMarie Wait a second... shouldn't $a = \frac{1}{2} \Psi_H$ and $b = \frac{1}{2} \Theta_H$? $\theta$ is the latitude and $\psi = \phi$ is the longitude.

Comment: You are right, my bad. I am accustomed to (french) notations where $\theta$ denotes longitude.

Comment: @JeanMarie I did not know that about French notations. Interesting and potentially alarming for cross border analysis!

Comment: You find this exchange $\theta \leftrightarrow \psi$ elsewhere, in other "latitudes" (!) like here in Asia (https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_to_convert_the_latitude_and_longitude_coordinates_to_Cartesian_Coordinates_which_involves_calculus)

Comment: And how do you find the 2d area from this coordinate parameters? I am guessing you integrate the length of segment over the perimeter? Is there a closed form solution for that?

Comment: @ali see the Edit I just wrote.

Comment: Thank you Jean. I don't think there's a closed form solution for the integral you posted?

Comment: @ali It is very doubtful...